# Results about specific geometric constructions in manifolds

Tags: geometry, soft-question, manifolds

In Euclidean geometry, we study results such as the Euler line.

[image: illustration of the Euler line]

There are several noteworthy results here. The orthocenter, circumcenter and centroid each exist! They are collinear! The centroid is always between the other two, and twice as far from the orthocenter as from the circumcenter!

This is of course very special about the geometry of the Euclidean plane. But the texts I read about geometry in non-euclidean manifolds were more concerned with the geometry of the space itself, and not with any constructions inside it. I think if we fix a (smooth, riemannian, whatever) manifold we should try to find something that is as special in it as the Euler line is in the Euclidean plane. Are there any results like this in the literature?